# how can I classify apps in a django website

Tags: django

I wanna create a website using django framework , I don't know how to divide the website into several apps... Help me.

In advance , thanks a lot
by the way , I'm new to web development

Comment: this is totally on you, divide your website based on actors and actions. think modularly. inside a blog platform, there could be a "blog" app to handle the posts, a "tag" app to handle tags, a "users" app to handle users. but mostly, this question doesn't fit SO's guidelines

Comment: opps , I'm sorry.where this question fits? thanks btw

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Django works by matching a URL pattern to some code that you have written in views.py.

In your case, you are pointing the same pattern (^$) to two view methods. Django will stop when it finds a match, so when you switch the patterns around, it will always match the first entry in the list.

If you change your patterns to:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
        url(r'^/two$', 'myapp2.views.home2', name='home2'),
        url(r'^$', 'myapp1.views.home1', name='home1'),
```

Now when you type **htt://localhost:8000/two** home2 will be executed, and when you type **http://localhost:8000/** home1 will be executed.

Comment: you are just talking about URL of django, it's not what i'm confused about . but thanks anyway .

Comment: Than its a design question, you need to decide based on how you are going to scale your site and how you want to manage your site